# Easy Tabs Plugin, always scroll to the top

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hi I am using Jquery EasyTabs Plugin for my website, follow the instruction from the online [Jquery EasyTabs plugin](http://os.alfajango.com/easytabs/).  It seem work fine; however, when I click on each tab, it always go to the top as the like '#tap1' unlike in its [demo](http://os.alfajango.com/easytabs/). I also checked the include path of its required js, css, and jquery file, they are correct already. 
Here are its required js and css files

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='style/jquery.js'></script>
<script src="style/jquery.hashchange.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="style/jquery.easytabs.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="style/tabs.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

and these are my HTML for tabs

```
        <!-- TABS -->
<div id='e-tabs' style='width:720px;height:auto;float:left;'>
            <div id="tab-container" class="tab-container">
          <ul class='etabs'>
            <li class='tab'><a href="#tabs1-html">Fatures</a></li>
            <li class='tab'><a href="#tabs1-js">Most Recent</a></li>
            <li class='tab'><a href="#tabs1-css">Most Popular</a></li>
          </ul>
          <div id="tabs1-html">
<!--            <h2>HTML Markup for these tabs</h2> -->
                <!-- content -->
                <div id='space'></div>
                    <div id='ads'>
                    <img src='ads-image\1.jpg'>
                    <div id='ads-title'><h4>Car for Sale</h4></div>
                    <div id='ads-price'><p>500$</p></div>
                    </div>
                                        <div id='ads'>
                    <img src='ads-image\1.jpg'>
                    <div id='ads-title'><h4>Car for Sale</h4></div>
                    <div id='ads-price'><p>500$</p></div>
                    </div>
                                        <div id='ads'>
                    <img src='ads-image\1.jpg'>
                    <div id='ads-title'><h4>Car for Sale</h4></div>
                    <div id='ads-price'><p>500$</p></div>
                    </div>
                                        <div id='ads'>
                    <img src='ads-image\1.jpg'>
                    <div id='ads-title'><h4>Car for Sale</h4></div>
                    <div id='ads-price'><p>500$</p></div>
                    </div>
                                        <div id='ads'>
                    <img src='ads-image\1.jpg'>
                    <div id='ads-title'><h4>Car for Sale</h4></div>
                    <div id='ads-price'><p>500$</p></div>
                    </div>
                                        <div id='ads'>
                    <img src='ads-image\1.jpg'>
                    <div id='ads-title'><h4>Car for Sale</h4></div>
                    <div id='ads-price'><p>500$</p></div>
                    </div>
                                        <div id='ads'>
                    <img src='ads-image\1.jpg'>
                    <div id='ads-title'><h4>Car for Sale</h4></div>
                    <div id='ads-price'><p>500$</p></div>
                    </div>
                                        <div id='ads'>
                    <img src='ads-image\1.jpg'>
                    <div id='ads-title'><h4>Car for Sale</h4></div>
                    <div id='ads-price'><p>500$</p></div>
                    </div>
                                        <div id='ads'>
                    <img src='ads-image\1.jpg'>
                    <div id='ads-title'><h4>Car for Sale</h4></div>
                    <div id='ads-price'><p>500$</p></div>
                    </div>
                                        <div id='ads'>
                    <img src='ads-image\1.jpg'>
                    <div id='ads-title'><h4>Car for Sale</h4></div>
                    <div id='ads-price'><p>500$</p></div>
                    </div>
                                        <div id='ads'>
                    <img src='ads-image\1.jpg'>
                    <div id='ads-title'><h4>Car for Sale</h4></div>
                    <div id='ads-price'><p>500$</p></div>
                    </div>
                                        <div id='ads'>
                    <img src='ads-image\1.jpg'>
                    <div id='ads-title'><h4>Car for Sale</h4></div>
                    <div id='ads-price'><p>500$</p></div>
                    </div>
                                        <div id='ads'>
                    <img src='ads-image\1.jpg'>
                    <div id='ads-title'><h4>Car for Sale</h4></div>
                    <div id='ads-price'><p>500$</p></div>
                    </div>
                                        <div id='ads'>
                    <img src='ads-image\1.jpg'>
                    <div id='ads-title'><h4>Car for Sale</h4></div>
                    <div id='ads-price'><p>500$</p></div>
                    </div>
                                        <div id='ads'>
                    <img src='ads-image\1.jpg'>
                    <div id='ads-title'><h4>Car for Sale</h4></div>
                    <div id='ads-price'><p>500$</p></div>
                    </div>
          </div>
          <div id="tabs1-js">
        <!--        <h2>JS for these tabs</h2> -->
                <!-- content -->

                    <div id='space'></div>
                        <div id='ads'>
                    <img src='ads-image\1.jpg'>
                    <div id='ads-title'><h4>Car for Sale</h4></div>
                    <div id='ads-price'><p>500$</p></div>
                    </div>
                                        <div id='ads'>
                    <img src='ads-image\1.jpg'>
                    <div id='ads-title'><h4>Car for Sale</h4></div>
                    <div id='ads-price'><p>500$</p></div>
                    </div>
                                        <div id='ads'>
                    <img src='ads-image\1.jpg'>
                    <div id='ads-title'><h4>Car for Sale</h4></div>
                    <div id='ads-price'><p>500$</p></div>
                    </div>
                                        <div id='ads'>
                    <img src='ads-image\1.jpg'>
                    <div id='ads-title'><h4>Car for Sale</h4></div>
                    <div id='ads-price'><p>500$</p></div>
                    </div>
                                        <div id='ads'>
                    <img src='ads-image\1.jpg'>
                    <div id='ads-title'><h4>Car for Sale</h4></div>
                    <div id='ads-price'><p>500$</p></div>
                    </div>
                                        <div id='ads'>
                    <img src='ads-image\1.jpg'>
                    <div id='ads-title'><h4>Car for Sale</h4></div>
                    <div id='ads-price'><p>500$</p></div>
                    </div>
                                        <div id='ads'>
                    <img src='ads-image\1.jpg'>
                    <div id='ads-title'><h4>Car for Sale</h4></div>
                    <div id='ads-price'><p>500$</p></div>
                    </div>
                                        <div id='ads'>
                    <img src='ads-image\1.jpg'>
                    <div id='ads-title'><h4>Car for Sale</h4></div>
                    <div id='ads-price'><p>500$</p></div>
                    </div>
                                        <div id='ads'>
                    <img src='ads-image\1.jpg'>
                    <div id='ads-title'><h4>Car for Sale</h4></div>
                    <div id='ads-price'><p>500$</p></div>
                    </div>
                                        <div id='ads'>
                    <img src='ads-image\1.jpg'>
                    <div id='ads-title'><h4>Car for Sale</h4></div>
                    <div id='ads-price'><p>500$</p></div>
                    </div>
                                        <div id='ads'>
                    <img src='ads-image\1.jpg'>
                    <div id='ads-title'><h4>Car for Sale</h4></div>
                    <div id='ads-price'><p>500$</p></div>
                    </div>
                                        <div id='ads'>
                    <img src='ads-image\1.jpg'>
                    <div id='ads-title'><h4>Car for Sale</h4></div>
                    <div id='ads-price'><p>500$</p></div>
                    </div>
                                        <div id='ads'>
                    <img src='ads-image\1.jpg'>
                    <div id='ads-title'><h4>Car for Sale</h4></div>
                    <div id='ads-price'><p>500$</p></div>
                    </div>
                                        <div id='ads'>
                    <img src='ads-image\1.jpg'>
                    <div id='ads-title'><h4>Car for Sale</h4></div>
                    <div id='ads-price'><p>500$</p></div>
                    </div>
                                        <div id='ads'>
                    <img src='ads-image\1.jpg'>
                    <div id='ads-title'><h4>Car for Sale</h4></div>
                    <div id='ads-price'><p>500$</p></div>
                    </div>


          </div>
          <div id="tabs1-css">
        <!--    <h2>CSS Styles for these tabs</h2> -->
            <!-- content -->
            <div id='space'></div>
                <div id='ads'>
                    <img src='ads-image\1.jpg'>
                    <div id='ads-title'><h4>Car for Sale</h4></div>
                    <div id='ads-price'><p>500$</p></div>
                    </div>
                                        <div id='ads'>
                    <img src='ads-image\1.jpg'>
                    <div id='ads-title'><h4>Car for Sale</h4></div>
                    <div id='ads-price'><p>500$</p></div>
                    </div>
                                        <div id='ads'>
                    <img src='ads-image\1.jpg'>
                    <div id='ads-title'><h4>Car for Sale</h4></div>
                    <div id='ads-price'><p>500$</p></div>
                    </div>
                                        <div id='ads'>
                    <img src='ads-image\1.jpg'>
                    <div id='ads-title'><h4>Car for Sale</h4></div>
                    <div id='ads-price'><p>500$</p></div>
                    </div>
                                        <div id='ads'>
                    <img src='ads-image\1.jpg'>
                    <div id='ads-title'><h4>Car for Sale</h4></div>
                    <div id='ads-price'><p>500$</p></div>
                    </div>
                                        <div id='ads'>
                    <img src='ads-image\1.jpg'>
                    <div id='ads-title'><h4>Car for Sale</h4></div>
                    <div id='ads-price'><p>500$</p></div>
                    </div>
                                        <div id='ads'>
                    <img src='ads-image\1.jpg'>
                    <div id='ads-title'><h4>Car for Sale</h4></div>
                    <div id='ads-price'><p>500$</p></div>
                    </div>
                                        <div id='ads'>
                    <img src='ads-image\1.jpg'>
                    <div id='ads-title'><h4>Car for Sale</h4></div>
                    <div id='ads-price'><p>500$</p></div>
                    </div>
                                        <div id='ads'>
                    <img src='ads-image\1.jpg'>
                    <div id='ads-title'><h4>Car for Sale</h4></div>
                    <div id='ads-price'><p>500$</p></div>
                    </div>
                                        <div id='ads'>
                    <img src='ads-image\1.jpg'>
                    <div id='ads-title'><h4>Car for Sale</h4></div>
                    <div id='ads-price'><p>500$</p></div>
                    </div>
                                        <div id='ads'>
                    <img src='ads-image\1.jpg'>
                    <div id='ads-title'><h4>Car for Sale</h4></div>
                    <div id='ads-price'><p>500$</p></div>
                    </div>
                                        <div id='ads'>
                    <img src='ads-image\1.jpg'>
                    <div id='ads-title'><h4>Car for Sale</h4></div>
                    <div id='ads-price'><p>500$</p></div>
                    </div>
                                        <div id='ads'>
                    <img src='ads-image\1.jpg'>
                    <div id='ads-title'><h4>Car for Sale</h4></div>
                    <div id='ads-price'><p>500$</p></div>
                    </div>
                                        <div id='ads'>
                    <img src='ads-image\1.jpg'>
                    <div id='ads-title'><h4>Car for Sale</h4></div>
                    <div id='ads-price'><p>500$</p></div>
                    </div>
                                        <div id='ads'>
                    <img src='ads-image\1.jpg'>
                    <div id='ads-title'><h4>Car for Sale</h4></div>
                    <div id='ads-price'><p>500$</p></div>
                    </div>
          </div>
        </div>
</div>
        <!-- TABS -->
```

Can anyone help me?
let me know should you need further information, Thanks

Comment: Are there any JavaScript errors in the console?

Comment: Yes, in firefox inspector console it shows like this `SyntaxError: Using //@ to indicate source map URL pragmas is deprecated. Use //# instead. jquery.min.js:1` `The character encoding of the HTML document was not declared. The document will render with garbled text in some browser configurations if the document contians characters from outside the US-ASCII range. The character encoding of the page must be declared in the document or in the transfer protocol. index.html` `Use of the getPreventDefault() is deprecated. Use defaultPrevented instead. jquery-2.0.3.js`

Comment: Most of those sound like warnings which shouldn't be an issue. Are you able to recreate the problem in http://jsfiddle.net?

Comment: here http://jsfiddle.net/82q5c/ sorry it's seem so long code for javascript panel because i don't know how to include those js file from my local computer so i copied and past all its contents directly. Or is there any other way i can show you? or need to send all my files to you? please advise thanks

Comment: Hi any update and solution for me?

Comment: can i use `return false or e.preventDefault()` to trigger this from following the link?

Comment: Give it a try. You can add third party libraries to your fiddle using the panel on the left. I don't really have time to look at it in detail at the moment, but there's more chance someone else will be able to help you if you can get a decent fiddle on the go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue in Google Chrome 39 but not in Firefox or Safari.

The problem is that Google Chrome 39 will jump to the element with the id of the hash, when `location.hash` is updated.

You can fix this by modifying `jquery.easytabs.js` version 3.2.0 to update the hash using `history.pushState({}, "", newHash)` instead of `location.hash = newHash`.
This [pull request](https://github.com/JangoSteve/jQuery-EasyTabs/pull/203/files) already does it for you.